# Manually via phpmyadmin add magento table

Tags: magento-1.9, custom

I've given up trying to make the SQL script for my custom module work, tried all sorts of things online and realized I've spent an hour on it when I can just manually create the table.

Just checking there isn't any issues with this? Like is there any foreign key checks etc.

**EDIT**

My install script:

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datasheetadmin_datasheetadmin` (
  `DatasheetAdmin_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `attribute_set_id` int(11)  NOT NULL,
  `header_row` text NOT NULL default '',
  `product_row` text NOT NULL default '',
  `custom_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL default 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DatasheetAdmin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. Maybe if you post your install script we can help you fixing it so you don't have to add the table manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your table will not be portable.
Each time you want your functionality that requires this table deployed on an instance you will have to create the table by yourself.
it's not a huge issue if you only have one table, but if do this once, you will do it again. Then you will lose track of what's what.  I still think you should create your table via script.
Here is how.

Create a module (let's call it `StackExchange_Demo`). Files needed:

`app/etc/modules/StackExchange_Demo.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Demo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </StackExchange_Demo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Demo/etc/config.xml` - the config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Demo>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackExchange_Demo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <stackexchange_demo_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>StackExchange_Demo</module>
                </setup>
            </stackexchange_demo_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Demo/sql/stackexchange_demo_setup/install-1.0.0.php` - the sql install script. When creating table you should use the DDL way of doing it, but if you can't do this you can take the simple approach:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("CREATE TABLE SQL STATEMENT GOES HERE");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Clear the cache and you are done.

Comment: could you tell me if theres anything wrong with my install script, did the rest of what you said :)

Comment: I see nothing wrong at a first glance. did you clear the cache?

Comment: it was an issue with my config and some other stuff, mainly using `app/code/local/StackExchange/Demo/sql/demo_setup/install-1.0.0.php` instead of `app/code/local/StackExchange/Demo/sql/stackexchange_demo_setup/install-1.0.0.php`